# How to identify if your screen device is projector or monitor

Tags: java, wmi

I would like to write a wmi and Java, or both, program that automatically finds and identifies display devices connected to my computer (Windows) is monitor or projector.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done in Java without JNI/JNA support.  What research have done into using WMI?

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure what you are trying to say but hope this helps you

[java.awt.Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) is the base class of all top level windows (Frame, JFrame, Dialog, etc.) and it contains the `getGraphicsConfiguration()` method that returns the [GraphicsConfiguration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html) that window is using.  GraphicsConfiguration has the `getGraphicsDevice()` method which returns the [GraphicsDevice](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) that the GraphicsConfiguration belongs to.  You can then use the [GraphicsEnvironment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) class to test this against all GraphicsDevices in the system, and see which one the Window belongs to.

```
Window myWindow = ....
// ...
GraphicsConfiguration config = myWindow.getGraphicsConfiguration();
GraphicsDevice myScreen = config.getDevice();
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
// AFAIK - there are no guarantees that screen devices are in order... 
// but they have been on every system I've used.
GraphicsDevice[] allScreens = env.getScreenDevices();
int myScreenIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < allScreens.length; i++) {
    if (allScreens[i].equals(myScreen))
    {
        myScreenIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("window is on screen" + myScreenIndex);
```

See the following:

[Link One](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html)

[Link Two](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html)

[Link Three](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html)

[Link Four](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html)

Comment: [1]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html
  [2]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html
  [3]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html
  [4]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html

Comment: Why don't you just edit your answer and put the links there? Why to write them in comment?

Comment: Because i am not allowed to do so. I can only post two links in anwser

Comment: How does that determine the type of device that the screen is?  How does it differentiate between a project and a (LCD) monitor?  I'm not sure how this answers the OP's question?